# Build tree categories from database table

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, orm, doctrine

**Hi, please. I have this table**

[image: Database table view]

And I need build php array from this table in symfony. I Have a code, but it build just 2 level... how I edit my function to get full array ? Thanks !

**My function**

```
  function buildCategoryTree(Category $parentCategory = null, Eshop $eshop)
{
    $categories = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository("AppBundle:Category")->findBy(array("parentCategory" => $parentCategory, "eshop" => $eshop));

    foreach ($categories as $category) {

        $url = $eshop->getHomepageOriginal() . $category->getLink();
        $arr = ["id" => $category->getId(), "name" => $category->getName(), "url" => $url, "active" => $category->getActive(), "last_http_status" => $category->getLastHttpStatusCode(), "child" => []];

        if (!$category->getParentCategory()) {

            $this->eshopCategoryTree[$category->getId()] = $arr;

        } else {

            $key = array_keys($this->eshopCategoryTree);
            $key = end($key);
            $this->eshopCategoryTree[$key]['children'][] = $arr;

        }

        $this->buildCategoryTree($category, $eshop);
    }
}
```

Comment: what does $category->getParentCategory() returns ?

Comment: Category entity

Comment: no i mean does it return that the current category have a parent ? or anything else

Comment: yes if current category have a parent

Comment: can you send a small dump of your db table i can send you a working example in PHP, then you can modify it in symfony.

Comment: It would be nice if you can include the `AppBundle:Category` mapping as well.

Comment: Anyway if you want to use tree structure and make sure that it is fast you should better use https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/v2.4.x/doc/tree.md .

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot. Table dump

```
CREATE TABLE `category` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `parent_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `eshop_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `link` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `last_check_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `last_http_status_code` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '200',
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `leaf` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `category` (`id`, `parent_id`, `eshop_id`, `name`, `link`, `created_at`, `last_check_at`, `last_http_status_code`, `active`, `leaf`) VALUES
(1, NULL, 1, 'Potraviny', '/kategorie/430-Potraviny/index.htm', '2017-01-11 11:21:47', '2017-01-11 11:21:47', 200, 1, 0),
(2, 1, 1, 'Mléčné výrobky', '/kategorie/431-Potraviny-Mlecne-vyrobky/index.htm', '2017-01-11 11:21:47', '2017-01-11 11:21:47', 200, 1, 0),
(3, 2, 1, 'Mléko', '/kategorie/432-Potraviny-Mlecne-vyrobky-Mleko/index.htm', '2017-01-11 11:21:47', '2017-01-11 11:21:47', 200, 1, 0),
(4, 3, 1, 'Mléko čerstvé', '/kategorie/433-Potraviny-Mlecne-vyrobky-Mleko-Mleko-cerstve/index.htm', '2017-01-11 11:21:47', '2017-01-11 11:21:47', 200, 1, 1),
(5, 3, 1, 'Mléko trvanlivé', '/kategorie/434-Potraviny-Mlecne-vyrobky-Mleko-Mleko-trvanlive/index.htm', '2017-01-11 11:21:47', '2017-01-11 11:21:47', 200, 1, 1),
(6, 3, 1, 'Mléko kondenzované', '/kategorie/435-Potraviny-Mlecne-vyrobky-Mleko-Mleko-kondenzovane/index.htm', '2017-01-11 11:21:47', '2017-01-11 11:21:47', 200, 1, 1),
(7, 3, 1, 'Mléko sušené', '/kategorie/436-Potraviny-Mlecne-vyrobky-Mleko-Mleko-susene/index.htm', '2017-01-11 11:21:47', '2017-01-11 11:21:47', 200, 1, 1),
(8, 3, 1, 'Mléčné nápoje', '/kategorie/437-Potraviny-Mlecne-vyrobky-Mleko-Mlecne-napoje/index.htm', '2017-01-11 11:21:47', '2017-01-11 11:21:47', 200, 1, 1),
(9, 3, 1, 'Tvarohy', '/kategorie/438-Potraviny-Mlecne-vyrobky-Tvarohy/index.htm', '2017-01-11 11:21:47', '2017-01-11 11:21:47', 200, 1, 0),
(10, 9, 1, 'Tvarohy neochucené', '/kategorie/439-Potraviny-Mlecne-vyrobky-Tvarohy-Tvarohy-neochucene/index.htm', '2017-01-11 11:21:47', '2017-01-11 11:21:47', 200, 1, 1),
(11, 9, 1, 'Tvarohy ochucené', '/kategorie/440-Potraviny-Mlecne-vyrobky-Tvarohy-Tvarohy-ochucene/index.htm', '2017-01-11 11:21:47', '2017-01-11 11:21:47', 200, 1, 1),
(12, 9, 1, 'Tvarohové dezerty', '/kategorie/441-Potraviny-Mlecne-vyrobky-Tvarohy-Tvarohove-dezerty/index.htm', '2017-01-11 11:21:47', '2017-01-11 11:21:47', 200, 1, 1),
(13, 9, 1, 'Tvarohové krémy a pomazánky', '/kategorie/442-Potraviny-Mlecne-vyrobky-Tvarohy-Tvarohove-kremy-a-pomazanky/index.htm', '2017-01-11 11:21:47', '2017-01-11 11:21:47', 200, 1, 1),
(14, 9, 1, 'Mléčné dezerty pudinky,rýže', '/kategorie/443-Potraviny-Mlecne-vyrobky-Mlecne-dezerty-pudinky-ryze/index.htm', '2017-01-11 11:21:47', '2017-01-11 11:21:47', 200, 1, 0),
(15, 14, 1, 'Mléčné dezerty', '/kategorie/444-Potraviny-Mlecne-vyrobky-Mlecne-dezerty-pudinky-ryze-Mlecne-dezerty/index.htm', '2017-01-11 11:21:47', '2017-01-11 11:21:47', 200, 1, 1),
(16, 14, 1, 'Mléčné pudinky', '/kategorie/445-Potraviny-Mlecne-vyrobky-Mlecne-dezerty-pudinky-ryze-Mlecne-pudinky/index.htm', '2017-01-11 11:21:47', '2017-01-11 11:21:47', 200, 1, 1),
(17, 14, 1, 'Mléčné rýže a krupice', '/kategorie/446-Potraviny-Mlecne-vyrobky-Mlecne-dezerty-pudinky-ryze-Mlecne-ryze-a-krupice/index.htm', '2017-01-11 11:21:47', '2017-01-11 11:21:47', 200, 1, 1),
(18, 14, 1, 'Mléčné výrobky vaření a pečení', '/kategorie/46059-Potraviny-Mlecne-vyrobky-Mlecne-dezerty-pudinky-ryze-Mlecne-vyrobky-vareni-a-peceni/index.htm', '2017-01-11 11:21:47', '2017-01-11 11:21:47', 200, 1, 1),
(19, 14, 1, 'Jogurty', '/kategorie/447-Potraviny-Mlecne-vyrobky-Jogurty/index.htm', '2017-01-11 11:21:47', '2017-01-11 11:21:47', 200, 1, 0),
(20, 19, 1, 'Jogurty bílé', '/kategorie/448-Potraviny-Mlecne-vyrobky-Jogurty-Jogurty-bile/index.htm', '2017-01-11 11:21:47', '2017-01-11 11:21:47', 200, 1, 1),
(21, 19, 1, 'Jogurty ovocné', '/kategorie/449-Potraviny-Mlecne-vyrobky-Jogurty-Jogurty-ovocne/index.htm', '2017-01-11 11:21:47', '2017-01-11 11:21:47', 200, 1, 1),
(22, 19, 1, 'Smetany živočišné a rostlinné', '/kategorie/451-Potraviny-Mlecne-vyrobky-Smetany-zivocisne-a-rostlinne/index.htm', '2017-01-11 11:21:47', '2017-01-11 11:21:47', 200, 1, 0),
(23, 22, 1, 'Smetany a šlehačky čerstvé a zakysané', '/kategorie/452-Potraviny-Mlecne-vyrobky-Smetany-zivocisne-a-rostlinne-Smetany-a-slehacky-cerstve-a-zakysane/index.htm', '2017-01-11 11:21:47', '2017-01-11 11:21:47', 200, 1, 1),
(24, 22, 1, 'Smetany a šlehačky trvanlivé', '/kategorie/453-Potraviny-Mlecne-vyrobky-Smetany-zivocisne-a-rostlinne-Smetany-a-slehacky-trvanlive/index.htm', '2017-01-11 11:21:47', '2017-01-11 11:21:47', 200, 1, 1),
(25, 22, 1, 'Smetany sušené', '/kategorie/454-Potraviny-Mlecne-vyrobky-Smetany-zivocisne-a-rostlinne-Smetany-susene/index.htm', '2017-01-11 11:21:47', '2017-01-11 11:21:47', 200, 1, 1),
(26, 22, 1, 'Sýry tavené a čerstvé', '/kategorie/455-Potraviny-Mlecne-vyrobky-Syry-tavene-a-cerstve/index.htm', '2017-01-11 11:21:47', '2017-01-11 11:21:47', 200, 1, 0),
(27, 26, 1, 'Sýry tavené', '/kategorie/456-Potraviny-Mlecne-vyrobky-Syry-tavene-a-cerstve-Syry-tavene/index.htm', '2017-01-11 11:21:47', '2017-01-11 11:21:47', 200, 1, 1),
(28, 26, 1, 'Sýry tavené plátky', '/kategorie/457-Potraviny-Mlecne-vyrobky-Syry-tavene-a-cerstve-Syry-tavene-platky/index.htm', '2017-01-11 11:21:47', '2017-01-11 11:21:47', 200, 1, 1),
(29, 26, 1, 'Sýry pomazánky', '/kategorie/458-Potraviny-Mlecne-vyrobky-Syry-tavene-a-cerstve-Syry-pomazanky/index.htm', '2017-01-11 11:21:47', '2017-01-11 11:21:47', 200, 1, 1),
(30, 26, 1, 'Sýry čerstvé', '/kategorie/459-Potraviny-Mlecne-vyrobky-Syry-tavene-a-cerstve-Syry-cerstve/index.htm', '2017-01-11 11:21:47', '2017-01-11 11:21:47', 200, 1, 1),
(31, 26, 1, 'Sýry termizované', '/kategorie/460-Potraviny-Mlecne-vyrobky-Syry-tavene-a-cerstve-Syry-termizovane/index.htm', '2017-01-11 11:21:47', '2017-01-11 11:21:47', 200, 1, 1),
(32, 26, 1, 'Sýry přírodní', '/kategorie/461-Potraviny-Mlecne-vyrobky-Syry-prirodni/index.htm', '2017-01-11 11:21:47', '2017-01-11 11:21:47', 200, 1, 0),
(33, 32, 1, 'Sýry přírodní-cihly,výkroje a bochníky', '/kategorie/462-Potraviny-Mlecne-vyrobky-Syry-prirodni-Syry-prirodni-cihly-vykroje-a-bochniky/index.htm', '2017-01-11 11:21:47', '2017-01-11 11:21:47', 200, 1, 1),
(34, 32, 1, 'Sýry přírodní- plátky a bločky', '/kategorie/463-Potraviny-Mlecne-vyrobky-Syry-prirodni-Syry-prirodni-platky-a-blocky/index.htm', '2017-01-11 11:21:47', '2017-01-11 11:21:47', 200, 1, 1),
(35, 32, 1, 'Sýry strouhané', '/kategorie/464-Potraviny-Mlecne-vyrobky-Syry-prirodni-Syry-strouhane/index.htm', '2017-01-11 11:21:47', '2017-01-11 11:21:47', 200, 1, 1),
(36, 32, 1, 'Sýry zrající', '/kategorie/465-Potraviny-Mlecne-vyrobky-Syry-prirodni-Syry-zrajici/index.htm', '2017-01-11 11:21:47', '2017-01-11 11:21:47', 200, 1, 1),
(37, 32, 1, 'Sýry balkánského typu', '/kategorie/466-Potraviny-Mlecne-vyrobky-Syry-prirodni-Syry-balkanskeho-typu/index.htm', '2017-01-11 11:21:47', '2017-01-11 11:21:47', 200, 1, 1),
(38, 32, 1, 'Sýry plísňové', '/kategorie/467-Potraviny-Mlecne-vyrobky-Syry-prirodni-Syry-plisnove/index.htm', '2017-01-11 11:21:47', '2017-01-11 11:21:47', 200, 1, 1),
(39, 32, 1, 'Sýrové speciality', '/kategorie/468-Potraviny-Mlecne-vyrobky-Syry-prirodni-Syrove-speciality/index.htm', '2017-01-11 11:21:47', '2017-01-11 11:21:47', 200, 1, 1),
(40, 32, 1, 'Másla,margariny,tuky a oleje', '/kategorie/471-Potraviny-Masla-margariny-tuky-a-oleje/index.htm', '2017-01-11 11:21:47', '2017-01-11 11:21:47', 200, 1, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a fix to your code making it work.

```
function main()
{
    // This is just a dummy function showing how you should use the buildCategoryTree() method
    $this->eshopCategoryTree = $this->buildCategoryTree(null, $this->eshop);
}

private function buildCategoryTree(Category $parentCategory = null, Eshop $eshop)
{
    $categories = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository("AppBundle:Category")->findBy(array("parentCategory" => $parentCategory, "eshop" => $eshop));

    $arr = [];

    foreach ($categories as $category) {

        $url = $eshop->getHomepageOriginal() . $category->getLink();

        $arr[$category->getId()] = [
            "id" => $category->getId(),
            "name" => $category->getName(),
            "url" => $url,
            "active" => $category->getActive(),
            "last_http_status" => $category->getLastHttpStatusCode(),
            "child" => $this->buildCategoryTree($category->getId(), $eshop)
        ];
    }

    return $arr;
}
```

The way you're trying to build a tree has many issues.

Firs of whole for each parent category you do SQL request to the DB. That is waste of the resources. It would be more reasonable to make one request and then iterate over the result in memory. As soon as this is a category list it won't be too big.

Another issue that you need to iterate through everything. If you use for example https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/v2.4.x/doc/tree.md and reorganise your DB you'll be able to build a tree much faster.

Another minor issue is the way you're generating the URL. It would be better to move this either to `Eshop` or to `Category` with method like (in case you put the method to `Category`)

```
public function getUrl(Eshop $eshop) { 
    return $eshop->getHomepageOriginal() . $this->getLink();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I found another solution, just add **children** to category entity. Symfony return already build tree.